# Mpirun segmentation fault 30% of the time

Tags: segmentation-fault, runtime-error, runtime, mpi, distributed-computing

I made a working barrier implementation in MPI, however sometimes it runs and sometimes but crashes on the last line (I think) of the main function. The strange thing is that it only crashes like 30% of the time.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <mpi.h>

void barrier(){    
    //Get rank and number of processors
    int my_rank, num_procs;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_procs); 
    //MPI Communication status var
    MPI_Status status;
    char b_req[1];
    //**Barier implementation for P0**
    if(my_rank == 0){
        double exec_start_all = MPI_Wtime();
        bool *nodes_barrier = (bool *)malloc(num_procs*sizeof(bool));  
        *(nodes_barrier)  = true;
        int start_count = 1; int end_count = 1; int i;
        //Set all values array, except for P0, on false
        for(i=1; i<num_procs; i++)
            *(nodes_barrier + i)  = false;
        //Receive msg from all procs which started their barrier
        while(start_count < num_procs){ 
            MPI_Recv(&b_req,sizeof(b_req),MPI_CHAR, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);            
            if(*(nodes_barrier + status.MPI_SOURCE) == false){                
                *(nodes_barrier + status.MPI_SOURCE) = true;
                start_count ++;  
            }
        }        
        //Once all procs started their barrier, send msg to all procs to release
        int j;
        for(j=1; j<num_procs; j++)
            MPI_Send(&b_req,sizeof(b_req),MPI_CHAR,j,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        //Get execution time of barrier from all procs and calculate the overal barrier execution time
        double *tmp = (double *)malloc(2*sizeof(double));
        double exec_end_all = MPI_Wtime();
        while(end_count < num_procs){ 
            MPI_Recv((double *)tmp,(2*sizeof(double)),MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);            
            if(*(nodes_barrier + status.MPI_SOURCE) == true){
                double start = ((double)*tmp+0);
                double end = ((double)*tmp+1);
                printf("P(%d) has start: %lf end: %lf \n",status.MPI_SOURCE, start, end);
                if(start < exec_start_all)
                    exec_start_all = start;                
                if(end > exec_end_all)
                    exec_end_all = end;                               
                *(nodes_barrier + status.MPI_SOURCE) = false;
                end_count ++;  
            }
        }        
        /*if(MPI_Wtime() > exec_end_all){
            exec_end_all = MPI_Wtime();
        }&*/
        printf("Barrier finished, start: %lf End: %lf Execution time: %lf \n", exec_start_all, exec_end_all,  (exec_end_all - exec_start_all));
        free(nodes_barrier);        
        free(tmp);


    //**Barier implementation for Pn-1 (except P0)**
    } else {
        double *execution = (double *)malloc(2*sizeof(double));
        *(execution + 0) = MPI_Wtime();
        //Send P0 that this proc starts its barrier
        MPI_Send(&b_req,sizeof(b_req),MPI_CHAR,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        //Receive command from P0 that it can release its barrier
        MPI_Recv(&b_req,sizeof(b_req),MPI_CHAR, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        //Measure and send execution time to P0   
        *(execution + 1) = MPI_Wtime();
        MPI_Send((double *)execution,(2*sizeof(double)),MPI_DOUBLE,0,3,MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
        free(execution);
    }    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    //Initialize the infrastructure necessary for communication
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    int my_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    barrier();


    printf("FINAL %d \n", my_rank);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Sometimes I get this error, note this always occurs at the end of the execution:

[image]

Sometimes I may get this error instead:

[image]

Does someone know what is going on? Or at least help me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you cannot use `MPI_BYTE` to transfer a `bool`. MPI allows you to use `MPI_C_BOOL` with `_Bool`.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I just changed the datatype to char (MPI_CHAR); _Bool was not supported, However, I still get the same error. Thanks for helping me tho :)

Comment: I also added a new picture of the full output of my program, as you can see the error occurs at the end of the execution.

Comment: generally speaking, do not use screenshots unless necessary. In this case, a copy/paste of the error is the best fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kind of errors in your program

- `MPI_Recv(&b_req,sizeof(b_req),...);` is incorrect, the buffer should be `b_req` (same issue with your `MPI_Send()`). Also, though `sizeof(b_req)` is correct here, it is misleading and you can hardcode `1` instead.
- `MPI_Send((double *)execution,(2*sizeof(double), ...);` is incorrect too (same issue with `MPI_Recv()`). The buffer is ok, but the size should be `2` instead of `2*sizeof(double)`.

These errors are causing an undetermined behavior and a buffer overflow, which explains why the behavior of your program is non deterministic.

That being said, since you do not care of the content of the messages used by the barrier, you can simply `MPI_Send(NULL, 0, MPI_CHAR, ...)` (same thing for `MPI_Recv()`).

Comment: Thanks! This fixed all my errors. Now I see what I did wrong.